# pdf form filled with mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am having pdf file.I want to fill some form field in pdf with data from mysql.
Using php data should be fetched from mysql & added at specific position in pdf file.

Can some one suggest me how can add mysql data at specific position in pdf file?

Comment: Are you creating the PDF file yourself, or trying to complete it automatically?

Comment: Actually i have to make decision on same.I already have pdf file & its 25 pages long.Its having more static content.So,i prefer that data will be fetched from mysql & placed at specific position in form

Answer (score 3):

Use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), fetch your data from mysql pass it to tcpdf function.

You will find plenty of examples & working codes here:
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

~K

---

If you want to create complete PDF using tcpdf then you can go ahead with it. This approac will allow you to make any change with ease in future prospective. There is a import class in TCPDF which i think is still in development.

If you want to use existing pdf & make few changes in it. Look  at     [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/), check [example here](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/):

Comment: the examples takes data & display in form format..My requirement is to place them at specific position in form..I would like to show sample output form for better understanding,but not possible to attach it using stackoverflow

Comment: [Sample output form ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oufg3h3ljwh0qnq/Vivek%20Sen_Securities_FormA.pdf
)